# What is the 3 Legged Oauth Implementation recommendation for a web app that accesses GCP data?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

(1) If you are using oauth2 flow like below:

[image: GCP Oauth2 Flow]

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

with [google-auth-library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) in a Node.js RESTful api and want to make an authenticated call to [Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage), what is the best practice (security, scalability, readability, common/popular patterns) for passing the credentials (access_token/id_token) from the auth flow endpoints to the Cloud Storage endpoints?

EXAMPLE SUDO CODE:

FILE A `server/AuthController.js`

`router.get("/generate-auth-url")` //generates auth url to send to client

`router.get("/auth-callback")` //google Api calls this in step 5, we exchange the code for an access_token and id_token, HOW DO WE PASS THIS DATA AROUND?

FILE B `server/CloudStorageController.js`

`router.get('/some-cloud-storage-json-file')`

which calls `const storage = new Storage({ credentials, projectId: "some-project-id" });` //how do i get credentials here from AuthController?

Bonus Questions:

(2) how do I validate auth on every follow up api call to an endpoint that accesses cloud storage data?

(3) what data do I need to store to maintain user session/authorization in your web app? (ex: access_tokens, id_tokens, refresh_token, cookies, etc)

(4) Where do I store said auth data? (ex: browser cookies, browser localStorage, nodejs session storage, database? (do you need a db for this architecture?), etc)

Comment: What do you mean "from the auth flow endpoints"?

Comment: the "auth flow endpoints" would be the endpoints in `server/AuthController.js`. the "flow" is the back and forth btwn the client/server/google api  to generate an auth url, send it to the client, getting user consent which then google will call whatever callback you set up in GCP API Credentials Oauth2 Settings, collecting the auth code from the query params in the callback url, exchanging the code for a access_token/id_token/refresh_token

Comment: Great response, sounds like you have it sorted out. "what is the best practice"? Do what is needed? Using TLS is always the best practice answer.

Comment: Do you want to reuse User token in your backend token?

Comment: I do not have it sorted out haha. I am looking for someone with experience in building production oauth. Yes, i have a solution that "works" but it does not meet security, scalability, readability, common/popular patterns needed for a production application.

Here is an example repo you can run locally https://github.com/jbobron/gcp-three-legged-oauth 

In this example, we need to pass the access_token/refresh_token from the AuthController to the CloudStorageController. What is the right way to do that in a production application?

Comment: OAuth is very easy to implement. You do not even need libraries. However, like most complex technologies, you need experience to deploy authorization systems. There are books describing OAuth. For Stack Overflow questions, please ask on-topic questions that can be answered with facts and or citations. Start with these guides: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Oauth is a very simple concept, but Google does not do a good job of describing how to productionize it. This is the point of my post, so im confused why you are asking to stay on-topic

Answer (score 0):

See this [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#node.js_1)

[This](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example) is the complete example for Node.js. Note where it says

> In a production app, you likely want to save the refresh token in a secure persistent database instead.